# python matrix string transpose without using numpy or zip/ map

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matrix, transpose

My current output is 3x1 matrix but I wish to have an output in horizontal matrix 1x3: `['apple', 'orange', 'grape']`

My python version is 3.5.1 and I fail to install numpy, I get an error if using `zip` or `map` to transpose as my variable is string not an integer.

Here is my code

```
import csv
#import numpy as np

f1 = open('out.csv')
data = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=':')
print (data)
for row in data:
    #print(row)
    modules = print(row[2:])
    #for row in module:

    result = [[0,0]]

# iterate through rows
for i in modules:
    # iterate through columns
    for j in modules[0]:
        result[j][i] = X[i][j]

for r in result:
    print(r)  

#Try with zip/map
#print(map(data,zip(*module))
#with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    #writer = csv.writer(f)
    #for row in module:
    #writer.writerow(module)
f1.close()
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "\python_exe\2.py", line 15,
>   in 
>       for i in modules: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: share what have you tried, error traceback and expected output

Comment: I modified my question at above

Comment: Do you want to turn [['apple'], ['orange'], ['grape']] into ['apple', 'orange', 'grape']?

Comment: yes, i want to turn into 1x3 matrix

Comment: Assuming your original matrix' name is `a`, just do `[x[0] for x in a]`

Comment: I get an error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Comment: `modules = print(row[2:])` is your problem, `print` does not return a value, so your `modules` becomes `NoneType`. Has nothing to do with any matrix transposition, just look carefully what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the list one item per line you can do something like this:

```
for item in mylist:
    print(item)
```

You can also look at the pretty print tools which will columnize and sort your list when it prints.

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(mylist)
```

Comment: it return me "NONE" with above modification